# como acceder a un contro datepicker desde ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hola que tal tengo un segmento de javascritp

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

No puedo acceder desde

```
DateTime calendario = Convert.ToDateTime(Page.Request.Form["datepicker"]);
```

se que es por el # del script pero no funcion ami datepicker con .datepikcer

Comment: El input sobre el cual se ejecuta el datepicker tiene el atributo `name` establecido a `datepicker`?

Comment: Si esta asi <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">

Comment: Cual es la relacion, como funciona uno y otro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando lo que te escribió Leandro Tuttini, podrías crear un HiddenField estático para que no cambie el nombre en el cliente. En su propiedad Value guardarás el valor del DateTimePicke y en el código detrás (code behind) puedes accesar a ese valor.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="miValor" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value="" />
```

En el código c#

```
 if (miValor.Value != "")
 {
     var a = miValor.Value;
 }
```

Y desde javascript:

```
let elemento = document.getElementById('miValor');
```

Comment: Porque tienes que hacer un pasamano del valor del type="date" a un hidden? si eso no es necesario. Si tienes mas de un control eso es inmantenible, plagarias la aplicacion de hidden

Answer (score 0):

Podrias agregar el `runat=server`

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" runat="server">
```

Para accederlo como un `Html Control` de esta forma

```
DateTime calendario = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker.Value);
```

pero desde el javascript valida si asp.net no cambia el id, sino deberias usar

```
$("[id*='datepicker']").datepicker();
```

al usar el `*=` es un selector tipo `like` o sea si contiene parte de ese texto que defines sobre el id

Comment: Gracias Leandro, voy a probar